# how to use the prototype of PromiseConstructorLike instance in interface declaration?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm trying to write declarations for Google Maps helper module for node, but I'm having problems with the PromiseConstructorLike that the library expects, and return it's "PromiseLike" instance methods properly (according to https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-js/docs/module-@google_maps.html):

```
Promise     function    <optional>  Promise constructor (optional).
```

so I did (stripped down to the interesting bits):

```js
declare namespace GoogleMaps {
  export interface CreateClientOptions<T> {
    /** Promise constructor (optional). */
    Promise?: T; 
  }

  export interface GoogleMapsClient<T> {
    directions<U>(query, callback?: ResponseCallback<U>): RequestHandle<U, T>;
  }

  export interface Response<U extends any> {
      headers: any;
      json: U;
      status: number;
  }

  export interface RequestHandle<U, T extends PromiseLike<Response<U>>> {
      asPromise(): T;
      cancel(): void;
      finally(callback: ResponseCallback<U>): void;
  }

  export type ResponseCallback<U> = (err: Error, result: Response<U>) => void; 
  export function createClient<T extends PromiseConstructorLike>(options: CreateClientOptions<T>): GoogleMapsClient<T>;
}

declare module '@google/maps' {
  export = GoogleMaps
}
```

of course it doesn't work, if I use for example, Bluebird in the `createClient` as

```js
import * as bluebird from 'bluebird'
import { createClient } from '@google/maps'

createClient({ Promise: bluebird }).directions({}).asPromise()/** no "then" here, just the static methods from Bluebird, like Bluebird.all */
```

The question is then:

**Is there anyway I can hint the `asPromise` method to return the instance methods (then, catch, finally, reduce, timeout, etc) from bluebird without having to extend the `RequestHandle` interface manually?**

More info (`lib.d.ts` declarations):

`PromiseConstructorLike` is:

```js
 declare type PromiseConstructorLike = new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) => PromiseLike<T>;
```

`PromiseLike` is:

```js
interface PromiseLike<T> {
    /**
     * Attaches callbacks for the resolution and/or rejection of the Promise.
     * @param onfulfilled The callback to execute when the Promise is resolved.
     * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
     * @returns A Promise for the completion of which ever callback is executed.
     */
    then(
        onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null,
        onrejected?: ((reason: any) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null): PromiseLike<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the release of Typescript 2.8, the new "infer" keyword makes this possible! it can infer (and pass on) intricate and nested declarations that the interpreter will try to fetch the information out for you, giving a really good strong typed experience.

so, if you want to get the type of the constructor

```
class MyPromise extends Promise<any> implements PromiseLike<any> {
    add(s: number) {
        s++
        return this
    }
    dummy() {
        return this
    }
}

function typedFactory<
    U extends PromiseConstructorLike,
>(u: U): InstanceType<U> {
    return new u<void>(() => { }) as any 
    // this isn't needed since we are just trying to show the functionality, 
    // would be interfacing another library through types only, so that 
    // the compiler doesn't b*tch about it
}

typedFactory(Promise).then(() => { })
typedFactory(MyPromise).add(1).dummy().then(() => {})
```

the new `InstanceType` is actually available in `lib.es5.d.ts` and is defined as:

```
type InstanceType<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

it shows the real power of the `infer` keyword, and you can try it in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Answer (score 1):

Your declarations contain a compile error, which stems from confusing the `Promise` *instance* type and the `Promise` *constructor* type. Type parameter `T` in `GoogleMapsClient` is used to fill `T` in `RequestHandle`, however in `GoogleMapsClient` this represents the `Promise` constructor type, while in `RequestHandle` it represents the `Promise` instance type.

It appears to be your intention to make everything properly typed in terms of the `Promise` *instance* type, `PromiseLike<Response<U>>`, where `U` is the response type. However, since `U` is not known in advance (i.e. before calling `GoogleMapsClient.directions`), this is unfortunately not possible.

If you want to call `then()` after `asPromise()`, you can simply change the return type of `RequestHandle.asPromise` to `PromiseLike<Response<U>>` and remove the type parameter `T`:

```
export interface RequestHandle<U> {
    asPromise(): PromiseLike<U>;
    cancel(): void;
    finally(callback: ResponseCallback<U>): void;
}
```

I would personally also add the constraint `extends PromiseConstructorLike` to type parameter `T` in both `CreateClientOptions` and `GoogleMapsClient`, so that the type-safety of the passed `Promise` constructor does not solely depend on the constraint specified in `createClient`.

To summarize, the declarations now look like this:

```
declare namespace GoogleMaps {
  export interface CreateClientOptions<T extends PromiseConstructorLike> {
    /** Promise constructor (optional). */
    Promise?: T; 
  }

  export interface GoogleMapsClient<T extends PromiseConstructorLike> {
    directions<U>(query, callback?: ResponseCallback<U>): RequestHandle<U>;
  }

  export interface Response<U extends any> {
      headers: any;
      json: U;
      status: number;
  }

  export interface RequestHandle<U> {
      asPromise(): PromiseLike<Response<U>>;
      cancel(): void;
      finally(callback: ResponseCallback<U>): void;
  }

  export type ResponseCallback<U> = (err: Error, result: Response<U>) => void; 
  export function createClient<T extends PromiseConstructorLike>(options: CreateClientOptions<T>): GoogleMapsClient<T>;
}

declare module '@google/maps' {
  export = GoogleMaps
}
```

With these declarations, your `bluebird` example works and you can call `then()` after `asPromise()`.

Comment: I don't want a generic `PromiseLike` in the `asPromise()`, I want `bluebird` functions (as I stated in my question) available in the `asPromise()` method, like `catch`, `map`, `each`, `bind`, `spread`, etc
using `PromiseLike` there defeats the purpose of using a `PromiseConstructorLike` in createClient

Comment: I stripped down the `U`, it actually extends one object for each method, the same with `query` parameter, so people would focus on the constructor/instance problem instead

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is not possible to create completely type-safe declarations that achieve what you want, due to the type parameter of the result type of a Promise. Note that 'new' in PromiseConstructorLike is also generic in the Promise result type, which means that PromiseConstructorLike cannot be made generic in the Promise type it returns, something that is required for solving this problem.

Comment: One thing you could do to get the right methods after calling 'asPromise' is making that method itself generic in the Promise instance type: 'asPromise<T extends PromiseLike<U>>(): T'. This does require specifying the correct Promise type whenever you call this method, and it is also not type-safe as you basically have to cast the result. Note that this trick could also be applied to the 'directions' method, which could then pass the Promise type to RequestHandle like you do now.

Comment: there is, there is `{ new(): T }` but it can't be used in this context